# Yarn gives error when creating a next.js application

Tags: windows, next.js, yarnpkg

I get this error because I have space present in my system username. How do I run this command successfully?

the error:

```
'C:\Users\Yatharth' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. error Command failed. Exit code: 1 Command: C:\Users\Yatharth Singh\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-next-app Arguments: panda command= C:\Users\Yatharth Singh\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-next-app
```

Comment: It seems to be because of the space between the name in the Profile folder "Yatarth Singh". Please run from a path without the spaces and you should be fine.

Comment: How can I change the path ?

Comment: Rename the folder from _Yatharth Singh_ to something like _Yatharth-Singh_

Comment: can you tell how can we rename the folder because it isn't renaming directly

Comment: Put it in quotes.